# ArcGIS 10 + wxPython: ArcGIS crashes when type 'import wx' in ArcMap python command window

Tags: crash, wxpython, compatibility, python-2.6, arcgis

my PC have ArcGIS 10 installed, which has Python 2.6.5 built-in.. I am trying to write a wxPython script and want to link this script and make it executable in ArcGIS.. to test the compatibility of wxPython and ArcGIS 10, I opened python command window in ArcMap, and typed

```
'import wx'
```

and then press 'enter'...

funny thing happened, ArcMap crashed!!

I did install a correct version of wxPython with Python 2.6.5...

so I am wondering if anybody knows what's going on? maybe there are some other libs I need to install before using wxPython?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change file extention from '.py' to '.pyw', will use pythonw.exe to compile it instead using default python.exe...

Answer (score 0):

According to the ArcGIS forums, it may be an incompatibility on ArcGIS's part: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17789-wxpython They seem to think PyQT will work better, but they don't really offer any proof.

I know Tkinter's IDLE doesn't always play nice with wx, but that only happens when you actually run a wx application from within it. And even then, I got it to work more often than not. I don't know why just importing it causes issues.

Comment: thanks for your help.. it turns out that using pythonw.exe as compiler solves this issue. so basically I just need to change 'XXX.py' as 'XXX.pyw'..